# Backup Hadoop in order to install new cluster, best practice

Tags: hadoop, backup, hdfs

I am building a new Hadoop cluster (expanding number of nodes and extending capacity of current nodes) and need to back up all of the existing data. Right now I am just tar-ing everything and sending it to another server.

Is there a smarter way of doing this which will allow me to easily deploy once the new cluster is set up?

Edit: I should also point out that I don't store any data on the cluster. I bring data to the cluster, process it, and then send the processed data back to the original server. Any temporary data on the cluster is the deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Distcp** to transfer the HDFS data to other cluster or any cloud inorder to store the data. 
If you want to schedule the Backup process you may avail **OOZIE-DISTCP** for backup process!!